# Running command in AWK

Tags: linux, awk, sendmail

I want to run sendmail command inside the awk, but I got the error below.

awk command

`awk '{ split($0,array,"@"); gsub("\."," ",array[1]); system("sendEmail -f foo@boo.com -t " $1 "-u \"Hello from command\" -m \"Dear\ " array[1] \"-s smtp.boo.com:587 -xu khikho -xp khikho"}' email_list.txt`

error:

`syntax error near unexpected token`('`

email_list.txt head:

`user.1@boo.com`

`user.2@boo.com`

`user.3@boo.com`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: get so your `system("sendmail ..." )` works with hard-code values all the way thru, THEN try to add simple variables, and do the array as the last item. Good luck.

Comment: You quotes inside system(..) are not correct.

Comment: 2 errors I see: no space before "-s" option; no closing parenthesis for `system(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a slightly different approach that's not quite so difficult to get all the quoting right in (also doesn't use `awk` at all, just the string parsing capabilities of `bash`):

```
while read address
do
  user=${address%%@*}
  sendEmail -f foo@boo.com -t ${address} -u "Hello from command" -m "Dear ${user}" \
       -s smtp.boo.com:587 -xu khikho -xp khikho
done < email_list.txt
```